# Where can i see how long i am muted

Tags: dota-2

Since Valve introduced a bug to receive unlimited reporttoken from successful reports (normally you would have a maximum of 4) everyone gets reported. A friend of mine has 270 reporttoken left.

Now I got reported again (because of this bug) and I wanted to know where I can find my remaining time of being muted.

Comment: Muted like, unable to talk in chat?

Comment: Just try to say something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should show in the chat box in the main menu as per this screenshot?

[image: Muted player screenshot]